# whats wrong with my multiplication table program in c

Tags: c

Can someone tell me the problem in my multiplication program?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    printf("enter the number of whose table you want");
    scanf("d", &b);
    for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
    {
        c = a * b;
        printf("%d\n", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output is showing irrelevant numbers

Comment: Did you compile with warnings enabled? There should be warnings or errors about missing includes, and the wrong argument to scanf.

Comment: Change `scanf("d",&b)` to `scanf("%d", &b)`. And please format your code :-)

Comment: You should [always] check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: `if (scanf("d",&b) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "scanf failure\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: also, you should initialize your variables on creation. 
In `int a=1`  the cast to int is unneccessary because you defined a to be an integer before.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` uses string format specifiers for reading. You would probably want to replace line 5 with `scanf("%d", &b);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the scanf function call. Instead of passing the correct format specifier for an integer (%d), you mistakenly used the letter "d." This causes the scanf function to misinterpret the input and not store it correctly in the variable b.

To fix the issue, you need to replace the incorrect format specifier "d" with "%d" in the scanf function. Here's the corrected version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Enter the number whose table you want: ");
  int b = 0;
  int status = scanf("%d", &b);
  if (status != 1) {
      printf("Failed to read input\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
  {
      int c = a * b;
      printf("%d\n", c);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

With this change, the program should work as expected.

Comment: General question: Why do C programmers still advocate to declare variables early instead of as late as possible? Is this just tradition or are there any benefits to it? Because declaring them late generally leads to fewer bugs and name collisions.

Comment: @chrysante It's a bad habit that dates back to C89 when it was mandatory.

Comment: I think a lot of it is habit since it was required in the past. IMO there are advantages. If all variables used within a function are declared in one place, they’re easier to find (vs. having declarations sprinkled throughout the code.) Also, it (can) help to avoid shadowing. @chrysante why do you consider it a bad habit?

Comment: @PaulLynch "If all variables used within a function are declared in one place, they’re easier to find (vs. having declarations sprinkled throughout the code.)" --> counter example here.  `int c = a * b;` is easier to find `c` than `int c;` declared elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> whats wrong with my multiplication table program

The key mistake is **not compiling with all warnings enabled**.

A good well enabled compiler will complain about

```
scanf("d",&b);
```

**Save time** and enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `%` in the `scanf()` format string. `scanf("d", &b)` reads a byte from standard input and matches it with `d`, if the byte is indeed a `d` it is consumed, otherwise it is pushed back.  If no byte was read, `scanf()` returns `EOF` and if a byte was read, `scanf()` will return `0` (the number of successful conversions) regardless of whether `d` was matched or not.

Note also that `a` is defined twice in the body of the function, the second definition shadows the first one and its scope only extends to the end of the `for` body. This is not causing your program to malfunction, but is potentially confusing and error prone.

You can fix these problems easily but there is more to learn more from this:

- always test the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid or  missing input;
- always compile your programs with all warnings enabled (ie: **gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror**) to take advantage of the compiler's consistency checks. Both **gcc** and **clang** would have spotted the problems immediately.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int b;

    printf("Enter the number of whose table you want: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &b) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
        int c = a * b;
        printf("%d x %d = %d\n", a, b, c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```